# Identity with Riemann Tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am currently reading some lecture notes on Riemannian geometry and it is stated that the fact that

$d|Rm|^2=2\langle Rm,\nabla Rm\rangle$

implies that

$\Delta|Rm|^2=2\langle Rm,\Delta Rm\rangle + 2|\nabla Rm|^2$.

Would someone mind clarifying why this is?  To define the notation, $\Delta$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator and $Rm$ is the Riemann curvature tensor.  $\nabla$ is the covariant derivative.

Comment: Could you define the quantities in your expression? Is $\Delta=\nabla^\mu\nabla_\mu$? What is $Rm$?

Comment: I've added in notation, Rm is just the Riemann tensor.

Comment: With laplacian, you mean the Laplace-Beltrami operator ($\Delta T=\nabla^{\alpha}\nabla_{\alpha}T$)?

Comment: Yes, sorry, the Laplace-Beltrami operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\Delta|Rm|^2&=\nabla^\mu\nabla_\mu|Rm|^2\\
&=\nabla^\mu2\langle Rm,\nabla_\mu Rm\rangle\\
&=2g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_\nu\langle Rm,\nabla_\mu Rm\rangle\\
&=2g^{\mu\nu}\langle\nabla_\nu Rm,\nabla_\mu Rm\rangle+2\langle Rm,g^{\nu\mu}\nabla_\nu\nabla_\mu Rm\rangle\\
&=2|\nabla Rm|^2+2\langle Rm,\Delta Rm\rangle.\end{align}$$